# Running Custom Bash Script Works in Terminal But Not RayCast

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, scripting

I'm writing a Raycast bash script that converts the most recent Screen Recording into a Gif using [this tool.](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207) The script is below. The line: `ffmpeg -i "$recent_file" -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > out.gif` works properly when run in Terminal. Unfortunately, it doesn't output `out.mov` when run in Raycast, despite the `fullOutput` of Raycast showing it completes as intended (see screenshot). Is there some kind of setting required in Raycast to allow the use of these command-line tools?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Required parameters:
# @raycast.schemaVersion 1
# @raycast.title Gif Most Recent Screen Recording
# @raycast.mode fullOutput

# Optional parameters:
# @raycast.icon 

# Documentation:
# @raycast.author willbeing
# @raycast.authorURL https://raycast.com/willbeing

directory="/Users/willbeing/Desktop/Screenshots"  # Replace with your desired directory

# Check if the directory exists
if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
  echo "Directory does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Check if the directory exists
if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
  echo "Directory does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Retrieve the most recent .mov file
recent_file=$(ls -t "$directory"/*.mov 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)

# Output the most recent .mov file
if [ -n "$recent_file" ]; then
  ffmpeg -i "$recent_file" -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > out.gif
else
  echo "No .mov files found in the directory."
fi
```

[image: Screenshot of Raycast output]

Comment: Enable xtrace (`PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x`), redirect stderr to a known location (`exec 2>/tmp/myscript.$$.log`) and read those logs; that way you'll be able to generate a detailed description of what went wrong. Right now this question is too broad to be a good fit for our form. That said -- also compare environment variables between the two environments; you can use `declare -p` to dump pretty much everything, or `env` to dump just the environment.

Comment: BTW, it's not likely to be the cause of your immediate problem, but `ls` is not well-suited to scripted use. See [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) describing how to find the newest file without it, and [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a more detailed description of why it's problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Where should `PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` and `2>/tmp/myscript.$$.log` go? I placed the first at the top of the script, and the second was less clear ( I assume somewhere within the `ffmpeg` or `gifsicle` commands. Would you mind scanning the environment variables for comparison? I'm unsure of what to look for. Terminal is at the top, Raycast at the bottom: https://codeshare.io/BAKMgO

Comment: `exec 2>/tmp/myscript.$$.log` (the `exec` is important) goes wherever you want to start redirecting stderr to the log, so probably up by the top; stderr from everything past the point will end up in a `myscript.<PID>.log` file.

Comment: The first thing I notice comparing those logs is that your interactive shell has both conda and node packages set up, and your Raycast instance's shell has neither.

Comment: The second thing I notice is that your interactive shell is zsh, not bash. But you _do_ have `/opt/homebrew/bin` in the PATH for both -- my first guess was that you'd installed ffmpeg or gifsicle through brew but didn't have it in the PATH during the noninteractive execution.

Comment: Anyhow -- once we know from the `set -x` trace which command fails, we can look at where its executable is at, and then we know which PATH entry is needed for it to work correctly.

Comment: Hmm. Though that trace doesn't show _either_ ffmpeg or gifsicle failing.

Comment: Again, thanks so much for the help. I hear you about conda and node, but neither are necessary for ffmpeg or gifsicle as far I as I'm aware. The zsh and bash differences shouldn't matter either. I'll look into the "but didn't have it in the PATH during the noninteractive execution." -- I did install both using brew (see installation instructions here: https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207) Here are the logs you created. They're nearly identical (for ffmpeg and gifsicle) to the terminal output https://codeshare.io/wnByZK

Comment: Question: Where are you looking for your output file? Looks to me like in the raycast case it would be created in the scripts directory, since that's what `PWD` is set to.

Comment: LOL -- that was it. It's in the scripts directory ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks for the help, @CharlesDuffy -- I appreciate you being so generous with your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254030/discussion-between-willbeing-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script worked as intended. Thanks to @CharlesDuffy I learned about some valuable debugging tools...

- Enable Retrace: `PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x`
- Redirect stderr to a known location: `exec 2>/tmp/myscript.$$.log`
- Compare environment variables between the two environments: you can use `declare -p` to dump pretty much everything or `env` for just environment.

...and of course to review the obvious, such as check the directory of the output file. In the raycast case it was the `scripts` directory (where I was not looking) ‍♂️